# How to load css in public files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

On my project i have following routes (routes.rb)

```
resources :main, path: '/' do
    collection do
      get 'about'
      get 'blog'
      get 'resources'
      get 'contact'
      get 'projects-and-tutorials'
    end
  end
```

and these routes are loading files from public folder like about.html and contact.html, right now no css file is loaded on these pages.

I have created a css folder under public folder and will load css file from there on these public pages but i am not sure if it is good to go with

how can i load css files from app/assets/stylesheets or there is another way to load css on public files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load the files app/assets/stylesheets(not visible publicly) inside the files in public directory.

You can create a separate directory inside public folder and put your css files there. and then you can refer them directly.

Comment: in that case i will need to copy code from assets css file, is there any method to use them ?

Comment: you need to copy the css